# How to call a declared SAS parameter

Tags: sas, macros, declare

I have declared a SAS parameter:

```
%let currentMonth = "June";
```

How do I print it out / find out what the value of `currentMonth` is
?

Comment: Did you really intend for the macro variable to have the six characters "June" in it?  It you want it to have just June then remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SAS macro variable, not a parameter.  There are many ways to diesplay the value of a macro variable, the easiest is with a %PUT statement:

```
%put The macro variable CurrentMonth has value: &CurrentMonth ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A useful statement is to create a log message that can be processed by a log viewer or log parser.  Four special prefixes of a log line are `INFO:` `NOTE:` `WARNING:` and `ERROR:`.  If you are logging a macro variable in the context of a macro, the macro name is also useful.

Example:

```
%macro xyzzy ;
  %put NOTE: &SYSMACRONAME: &=CurrentMonth ;
%mend ;
%xyzzy
```

will log

```
NOTE: XYZZY: CurrentMonth="June" ;
```

The macro syntax `&=<symbol>` will log `<symbol>=<value-of-symbol>`